# Not recognizing object parameter as int

Tags: python, class, object

```
class Ball:
    def __init__(self,pos,vel):
        self.pos = Vector(pos.x,pos.y)
        self.vel = Vector(vel.x,vel.y)
    def curx(self):
        return (self.pos.x + self.vel.x)
    def cury(self):
        return (self.pos.y + self.vel.y)
    def forcex(velx):
        self.vel.deltax(velx)
    def forcey(vely):
        self.vel.deltay(vely)

class Vector:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def x(self):
        return self.x
    def y(self):
        return self.y
    def delx(self,deltax):
        self.x = self.x + deltax
    def dely(self,deltay):
        self.y = self.y + deltay
```

Here are my two classes, but when I initialize and try to get curx or cury back from ball:

```
ball = Ball(Vector(0,0),Vector(0,0))
print ball.curx
```

I get: `<bound method Ball.curx of <__main__.Ball instance at 0x1142fd0>>`

I feel like there should be a fairly simple answer to this and I'm just not getting it.

Comment: you have to use `()`...

Comment: Okay, so I did that and now I'm getting different error which makes zero sense to me... TypeError: curx() takes no arguments (1 is given)

Comment: @user3128305 - You must be passing in an argument to `Ball.curx` somehow.  Please see the demonstration I gave in my answer.  If you run the code exactly as I did, it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`curx` is a method of `Ball`.  So, you have to invoke it:

```
print ball.curx()
```

---

**Edit:**

@user2357112 has noticed two more problems:

1. The definitions of `Ball.forcex` and `Ball.forcey` are missing their `self` parameters.
2. `Vector.x` and `Vector.y` are entirely useless methods.  You already have `x` and `y` as attributes of `Vector` through `self.x` and `self.y`.  So, you should just remove the methods altogether.

Here is how the code should be:

```
class Ball:
    def __init__(self,pos,vel):
        self.pos = Vector(pos.x,pos.y)
        self.vel = Vector(vel.x,vel.y)
    def curx(self):
        return (self.pos.x + self.vel.x)
    def cury(self):
        return (self.pos.y + self.vel.y)
    def forcex(self, velx):
        self.vel.deltax(velx)
    def forcey(self, vely):
        self.vel.deltay(vely)

class Vector:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def delx(self,deltax):
        self.x = self.x + deltax
    def dely(self,deltay):
        self.y = self.y + deltay
ball = Ball(Vector(0,0),Vector(0,0))
print ball.curx()
```

Comment: Indeed, though it might in this case be entirely reasonable for `curx`, `cury`, `forcex`, and `forcey` and so on to be implemented as properties:  Just drop a `@property` on top of each method definition and you'll be all set, and won't have to use the `()` method call syntax to access them--they would just be accessible as normal attributes.

Comment: It's also worth noting that `forcex` and `forcey` are missing their `self` parameters.

Comment: The `x` and `y` methods of `Vector` won't work, since they're hidden by the `x` and `y` instance attributes. The OP might not notice the bug, since if he's leaving off the method call parentheses, it would look as if the method was being called.

Comment: @user2357112 - I have edited my answer to incorporate your advice.  Thanks for the help.